# Rails model: declaratively expressing relation between attributes for presenting, computation and storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, metaprogramming, idioms

Imagine the situation:

In my rails model i use IceCube::Schedule to represent recurring calendar events pattern (e.g. "Every 2nd Monday of a month"). So i have 3 kinds of attributes in my model:

- for computation: schedule
- for storing: database column which stores schedule.to_yaml: schedule_yaml
- for presenting: set of attributes, that are used for input/output of schedule parameters: interval_unit, interval_amount, weekdays etc

Depending on scenario, from one category of attributes computed the others:

- Process input: presenting attributes -> computing -> storage
- Processing invalid input: presenting -> validation
- Preparing input form: storage -> computing -> presenting
- Computing (next date in the sequence): storage -> computing -> storage

All the parts of the system are no-brainer, except for computing. Though they may need quite a lot of code to implement the updating of the related attributes properly properly.

Do you know some gem or at least some idioms to do that in an elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of https://github.com/ablegray/schedule-attributes?

It handles presentation for IceCube backed models.